# Link between Hodge conjecture and Motives theory.

Tags: category-theory

Is there a version of the rational Hodge conjecture in terms of Motives theory or categories theory ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hodge conjecture has a very strong connection with motives. In fact, Hodge conjecture is equivalent to the fact that the Hodge realization is full, and it implies all the standard conjectures over any field of characteristic 0.

Comment: See also Matthew Emerton's answer here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54197/why-is-the-hodge-conjecture-so-important

Comment: You might look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/236820/big-list-equivalent-descriptions-of-hodge-conjecture